# SKPhysicsBody float like a balloon

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

I'm sure this is somewhere already on the internet, but I can't seem to find it. Say I want to add some balloons that float upwards in a scene (where gravity is downwards for everything else). What's the best way to go about it?
So far, I have set the balloon's mass to almost nothing, and applied an upwards force to it. It seems to work okay, but I'm hoping there is a more appropriate way of doing it.

Thank you

Comment: more appropriate in terms of what? The only alternative would be to use a negative gravityScale but either way works fine.

Comment: Your way seems appropriate enough.

Comment: Here's a good answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063822/spritekit-making-a-sprite-defy-gravity-like-a-balloon][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063822/spritekit-making-a-sprite-defy-gravity-like-a-balloon