# SpriteKit - Making a sprite defy gravity (like a balloon)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Does anyone have any idea how I can make my `SKSpriteNode` defy gravity? I thought of inverting the default gravity but realise I also need things to fall too!

It seems like it should be easy but reading through the documentation I can’t see how I would do it!

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "float"?

Comment: @Fogmeister Good point - See edit :)

Comment: Have you tried setting a negative mass?

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** In iOS 8 / OS X Yosemite (10.10), physics fields provide an elegant solution to these sorts of problems. Here's a quick take on using them to add buoyancy (for a specific set of nodes) to your scene.

1. Create an `SKFieldNode` with the [`linearGravityFieldWithVector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/linearGravityFieldWithVector:) constructor, providing a vector that's the opposite of gravity, and add the field node to your scene.
2. Set the [`fieldBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/fieldBitMask) on your balloons to something unique.
3. Set the [`categoryBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKFieldNode/categoryBitMask) on the field to something that overlaps with the balloons' `fieldBitMask`, but that does not overlap with the `fieldBitMask` of any other bodies.

Now, the balloons will rise or hold steady, but other objects will fall. Tweaking the field's `strength` will let you tune whether the balloons' buoyancy is perfectly balancing gravity (so that they float in place, but are disturbed when touched), or slightly more or less than gravity (so that they slowly rise or fall).

By default, a field is infinite, covering the whole scene, but you can change that with the field's [`region`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKFieldNode/region) property to limit it to a portion of the scene. (This is useful if you want to simulate buoyancy in water — once an object rises past the top of the field at the water's surface, it falls back in.)

Also, if you want variable buoyancy as per [@TheisEgeberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069349/957768), you can control its variation over distance with the [`falloff`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKFieldNode/falloff) property.

In iOS 7 / OS X Mavericks (10.9), or if you want more precise control over which forces apply where and when, you can use the approach from my original answer below.

---

If you want an object to really float like a balloon — that is, to be buoyant, affected by gravity but also counteracting it — you'll need to apply a force to it on every frame (i.e. in your `update:` method).

Beware scaling: gravity is a constant acceleration, but if you're applying a force to counteract gravity, a force is proportional to mass. To make a vector that perfectly balances gravity for use in `applyForce:`, you'll need to:

1. scale the gravity vector by `{-1,-1,-1}` to point in the opposite direction
2. scale by the `mass` of the body you're applying the force to (`F = ma`, where gravity or anti-gravity is `a`).
3. scale by `150` — there's a bug where the `SKPhysicsWorld.gravity` property isn't in the same units as `applyForce:`. (If you turn `SKPhysicsWorld` gravity off and use `SKFieldNode` gravity instead, you don't need to do this.)

Unlike turning off `affectedByGravity` and applying an action to make the balloon rise, this approach works well with the rest of the physics sim. With a balancing force exactly equal to gravity, the balloon will float in place — after colliding with other things it'll return to equilibrium. If the balancing force is greater than gravity, the balloon will rise, but its rise will be hindered by other bodies in its way.

Answer (score 2):

First off, an `SKSpriteNode` isn't affected by gravity at all. It is the `SKPhysicsBody` that belongs to the node that is affected by gravity.

Second...

```
myNode.physicsBody.afectedByGravity = NO;
```

:D

If you want it to rise upwards then you can add an action to it...

```
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-10 duration:1];

SKAction *repeatingAction = [SKAction repeatActionForever:moveAction];

[myNode runAction:repeatingAction];
```

Comment: You’re right it is a `SKPhysicsBody` that I mean, however, I toyed with the idea of turning off `affectedByGravity` but that doesn’t defy gravity, it just turns it off

Comment: Only on that specific body. Is that not what you want? Describe exactly what you would like to happen. You asked how to defy gravity and this is it. But now that's not what you want.

Comment: Defying gravity would be gravity being turned on and the object’s force is greater in the y direction, therefore pushing it up in the air. This is what I want to happen to my sprite.

Answer (score 1):

As many have said it's about counterforce.

So yes, you can apply a counterforce to the balloon to make it go upwards.

But to make it look like a balloon you need to understand what makes a balloon go up: Air pressure. Since the helium or whatever light gas you are using is lighter than air it will start to go up, or in other words the heavier air will go under the balloon. It's like a piece of wood in water, the heavier water will go under the wood, till the wood is soaked and gets even heavier than the water.

So what you should do is to make the counterforce adapt to the height of the balloon, the higher it gets the less pressure you apply upwards. This is a way to simulate buoyancy.

Comment: That's a very good point — real world buoyancy is typically variable. However, in building games it's also good to pick the right level of abstraction for the job, so you don't needlessly complicate your design or hinder your performance. Do you want a game where a balloon's lift varies within the amount of space allotted for gameplay? Great — use variable buoyancy. Otherwise stick to something simple. (Note my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24065250/957768) addresses both.)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my answer:

```
- (MyClass *)newRisingObject
{
    MyClass *risingObject = [MyClass spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"image"];

    [risingObject setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))];
    [risingObject setName:@"name"];
    [risingObject setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    //  Physics
    //
    [risingObject setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:risingObject.size.width / 2.0f]];
    [risingObject.physicsBody setRestitution:1.0f];
    [risingObject.physicsBody setFriction:0.0f];
    [risingObject.physicsBody setLinearDamping:0.0f];
    [risingObject.physicsBody setAngularDamping:0.0f];
    [risingObject.physicsBody setMass:1.3e-6f];

    return risingObject;
}
```

.

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    /* Setup your scene here */
    MyClass *risingObject = [self newRisingObject];

    [self addChild:risingObject];
}
```

.

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"name"
                           usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
     {
         //  Push object up
         //
         [node.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0f, node.physicsBody.mass * OBJECT_ACCELERATION)];
    }];
}
```